# Request Payload shows credentials in clear text even on https

Tags: node.js, angularjs, https, payload

I am posting login credentials from angularjs to node js rest api. My express server in node js is running on https however, when i am posting the credentials to authentication api in chrome developer tool i can see request payload for the request with clear text credentials.

I am sure over https information should be in encrypted form but here i can see the request payload in clear text.

### Auth.js (Angular JS)

```
var user = {
    username: $scope.username,
    password: $scope.password
}

Auth.validatePassword(user)
```

---

### Services.js (Angular JS)

```
var validatePassword = function (data) {
    return $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/api/validatepassword",
        data: data
    })
    .then(function (res) {
        return res.data;
    })
}
```

---

### routes.js (Node JS)

```
app.post('/api/validatepassword', dbHandler.validatePassword);
```

---

### dbhandler.js (node js)

```
validatePassword: function (req, res, err) {
    objPass = new getPassword(req.body.username);

    objPass.then(function (data) {
        var strPassword = crypt.encrypt(req.body.password);

        if (strPassword != data[0].Password) {
            var errMsg = {
                Error : true
            }
            res.json(errMsg);
        } else {
            res.json(data);
        }
    }, function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    })
}
```

---

### index.js (Node JS)

```
var port = process.env.PORT;
    var host = process.env.HOST;

    https.createServer({
        key: key,
        cert: cert
      }, app)
      .listen(port, host);
```

---

[Request Payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbN76.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well...  of course your browser sees your request unencryptedly, and shows it to you. It encrypts it, so it of course has the capability to view the unencrypted request. Just try it on other websites (i.e. Google, and they take your security very seriously), you can see, what you send, anywhere. 
Else it would be hard to debug.

TLDR: It's not a bug, it's a feature!

Comment: will that be visible in wireshark for example? or any sniffing tool ?, i am also searching how to securely pass the credentials to backend API for authentication

Comment: Sorry I'm late, as I stated, with HTTPS on, no. Your browser does the encryption, so it naturally knows what it is encrypting. Any sniffing tool comes way after that (does not run on the machine in question). So then everything is encrypted.